# Different content in the tabs

Tags: java, android, tabs, pagerslidingtabstrip

I'm using [this](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) android studio project, but I didn't know how to change content there.For example, I want to have a text "Hello World" in the first tab, the text "Goodbye..." in the second tab and so on... Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try anything? There is a sample folder where you can find an example. In the first file I opened, which is `MainActivity.java`, there is a class called `MyPagerAdapter`, with the following line:

```
private final String[] TITLES = { "Categories", "Home", "Top Paid", "Top Free", "Top Grossing", "Top New Paid", "Top New Free", "Trending" };
```

Seems to me you can change that to

```
private final String[] TITLES = {"Hello world", "Goodbye..."};
```

If that doesn't work you do have a valid question, but in this case you should have checked the sample first. Literraly took me less than a minute to find.

Comment: Sorry for my English. May be you understand me wrond. I meant to change it like this(Images) I want to have different text here.In file "SuperAwesomeCardFragment.java": v.setText("CARD " + (position + 1)); But I want to have different text.

Images:

http://i.stack.imgur.com/bmwRC.png http://i.stack.imgur.com/aDNe1.png

Comment: Then use a different fragment if you want a completely different kind of content (can't help you with that, since it would practically mean me writing your app, but google can help you here), or use v.setText("This is the text I do want");. You could use a switch case to check the tab position and issue the right v.setText at the right position.

Comment: I've edited your question. Replace the v.setText line with: if (position == 0){ v.setText("Hello World") } else if (position == 1) { v.setText("Goodbye...") } and it should do what you want.